# Rails not reloading classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails app in development mode that is not reloading any model/controller classes upon modifying the files unless the dev server is reset. The same exact project used to reload the files fine but without any apparent changes it is no longer working.

I have `config.cache_classes = false` set in my development.rb file. I have also confirmed that I am running in development mode. I have went as far as printing the cache_classes variable out to the screen with the server running to confirm it is false, which it is.

I am not running in threadsafe mode, I read this can mess the the cache_classes setting.

I have also confirmed that the timestamps on the files are being updated when I save them. I am running Rails 3.2.13. I have the same result when using either webrick or pow. What could be causing the classes to not being reloaded?

Comment: Can you please provide steps to reproduce this issue? Can you reproduce it in a new application? It's pretty hard for us to debug this issue without anything to go on.

Comment: When I simply edit any model or controller in my project and save it the changes do not have any affect until I restart the server. I created a new project and it works properly.

Comment: Then I'd say it's a gem that you're using. Try removing gems from your Gemfile and reproducing the problem and see what happens.

Comment: It's not...I removed all the gems in my gemfile except the default rails ones and still had the same issue.

Comment: Paste your development.rb file, your GemFile, and the output of the server console when you start it